# How to bridge two SOAP services with node.js

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, wsdl

I had a Soap service which was consumed by another service. Now, our architecture has changed and the consumer has no access to the source Soap service, so we have to adapt our public API, developed with `node.js`, in order to communicate both services. Something like a bridge between them.

This has to be this way because we can't move the consumer service into the private environment where the Soap service has  been placed, and also we can't modify the consumer in order to be able to query REST services.

I've tried to make it work with different libraries, as:

- [`rest-to-soap-mapper`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rest-to-soap-mapper) To make calls to the Soap service from the API. I've been able to call it but I can't see how the original consumer could call this API as a Soap service.
- [`soap`](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap)This is supposed to be a client and a server, and should be able to help me to reach what I want, but when I try to configure it as server, as it is explained [in this example](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#options-1), I get some errors...(I just have the `wsdl` url to configur it).
- [`soap-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap-server) It seems that I need to build the service in the API...if I could point to the external Soap service I think it could work...

So do you know any way to 'build' this bridge with any of these tools or any other?